# How can I add a cipher_suite to the Erlang default ones?

Tags: ssl, rabbitmq, erlang

I'm currently trying to add the cipher TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA_256 to my default cipher_suite in Erlang 24 (on a CentOS 8 machine). Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to do so.

I know that the cipher is their cause:

```
1> ssl:str_to_suite("TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA_256").
```

returns:

```
#{cipher => aes_128_cbc,key_exchange => psk,mac => sha256,
  prf => sha256}
```

I do also know that the cipher is not activate cause

```
rp(ssl:cipher_suites(default,'tlsv1.2')).
```

does not list it:

```
[#{cipher => aes_256_gcm,key_exchange => ecdhe_ecdsa,
   mac => aead,prf => sha384},
 #{cipher => aes_256_gcm,key_exchange => ecdhe_rsa,mac => aead,
   prf => sha384},
 #{cipher => aes_256_ccm,key_exchange => ecdhe_ecdsa,
   mac => aead,prf => default_prf},
 #{cipher => aes_256_ccm_8,key_exchange => ecdhe_ecdsa,
   mac => aead,prf => default_prf},
 #{cipher => aes_256_cbc,key_exchange => ecdhe_ecdsa,
   mac => sha384,prf => sha384},
 #{cipher => aes_256_cbc,key_exchange => ecdhe_rsa,
   mac => sha384,prf => sha384},
 #{cipher => chacha20_poly1305,key_exchange => ecdhe_ecdsa,
   mac => aead,prf => sha256},
 #{cipher => chacha20_poly1305,key_exchange => ecdhe_rsa,
   mac => aead,prf => sha256},
 #{cipher => aes_128_gcm,key_exchange => ecdhe_ecdsa,
   mac => aead,prf => sha256},
 #{cipher => aes_128_gcm,key_exchange => ecdhe_rsa,mac => aead,
   prf => sha256},
 #{cipher => aes_128_ccm,key_exchange => ecdhe_ecdsa,
   mac => aead,prf => default_prf},
 #{cipher => aes_128_ccm_8,key_exchange => ecdhe_ecdsa,
   mac => aead,prf => default_prf},
 #{cipher => aes_256_gcm,key_exchange => ecdh_ecdsa,
   mac => aead,prf => sha384},
 #{cipher => aes_256_gcm,key_exchange => ecdh_rsa,mac => aead,
   prf => sha384},
 #{cipher => aes_256_cbc,key_exchange => ecdh_ecdsa,
   mac => sha384,prf => sha384},
 #{cipher => aes_256_cbc,key_exchange => ecdh_rsa,
   mac => sha384,prf => sha384},
 #{cipher => aes_128_gcm,key_exchange => ecdh_ecdsa,
   mac => aead,prf => sha256},
 #{cipher => aes_128_gcm,key_exchange => ecdh_rsa,mac => aead,
   prf => sha256},
 #{cipher => aes_128_cbc,key_exchange => ecdhe_ecdsa,
   mac => sha256,prf => sha256},
 #{cipher => aes_128_cbc,key_exchange => ecdhe_rsa,
   mac => sha256,prf => sha256},
 #{cipher => aes_128_cbc,key_exchange => ecdh_ecdsa,
   mac => sha256,prf => sha256},
 #{cipher => aes_128_cbc,key_exchange => ecdh_rsa,
   mac => sha256,prf => sha256},
 #{cipher => aes_256_gcm,key_exchange => dhe_rsa,mac => aead,
   prf => sha384},
 #{cipher => aes_256_gcm,key_exchange => dhe_dss,mac => aead,
   prf => sha384},
 #{cipher => aes_256_cbc,key_exchange => dhe_rsa,mac => sha256,
   prf => default_prf},
 #{cipher => aes_256_cbc,key_exchange => dhe_dss,mac => sha256,
   prf => default_prf},
 #{cipher => aes_128_gcm,key_exchange => dhe_rsa,mac => aead,
   prf => sha256},
 #{cipher => aes_128_gcm,key_exchange => dhe_dss,mac => aead,
   prf => sha256},
 #{cipher => chacha20_poly1305,key_exchange => dhe_rsa,
   mac => aead,prf => sha256},
 #{cipher => aes_128_cbc,key_exchange => dhe_rsa,mac => sha256,
   prf => default_prf},
 #{cipher => aes_128_cbc,key_exchange => dhe_dss,mac => sha256,
   prf => default_prf},
 #{cipher => aes_256_cbc,key_exchange => ecdhe_ecdsa,
   mac => sha,prf => default_prf},
 #{cipher => aes_256_cbc,key_exchange => ecdhe_rsa,mac => sha,
   prf => default_prf},
 #{cipher => aes_256_cbc,key_exchange => ecdh_ecdsa,mac => sha,
   prf => default_prf},
 #{cipher => aes_256_cbc,key_exchange => ecdh_rsa,mac => sha,
   prf => default_prf},
 #{cipher => aes_128_cbc,key_exchange => ecdhe_ecdsa,
   mac => sha,prf => default_prf},
 #{cipher => aes_128_cbc,key_exchange => ecdhe_rsa,mac => sha,
   prf => default_prf},
 #{cipher => aes_128_cbc,key_exchange => ecdh_ecdsa,mac => sha,
   prf => default_prf},
 #{cipher => aes_128_cbc,key_exchange => ecdh_rsa,mac => sha,
   prf => default_prf},
 #{cipher => aes_256_cbc,key_exchange => dhe_rsa,mac => sha,
   prf => default_prf},
 #{cipher => aes_256_cbc,key_exchange => dhe_dss,mac => sha,
   prf => default_prf},
 #{cipher => aes_128_cbc,key_exchange => dhe_rsa,mac => sha,
   prf => default_prf},
 #{cipher => aes_128_cbc,key_exchange => dhe_dss,mac => sha,
   prf => default_prf}]
```

I need this cipher cause I want to connect to RabbitMQ (with the MQTT Plugin) for a device.

Does anyone know how to activate/enable a cipher in Erlang ?

Comment: This cipher seems to be supported, though it's not in the `default` list, only in the `anonymous` list: `lists:member(ssl:str_to_suite("TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256"), ssl:cipher_suites(anonymous, 'tlsv1.2'))` returns `true`.

Comment: Hi @legoscia,

Thanks for you answer. In fact the command does returns true. Is it possible to move it from anonymous to Default such that rabbitmq can regonize it ?

Comment: As far as I understand, the way to do that is to add the cipher to the `ciphers` option in `ssl_options`, as mentioned here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html Not sure what the exact syntax would be.

Comment: I already added the line in the conifguration file as it is mentioned by rabbitmq. Unfortunately, this did not do the trick. I was assuming that this might be because Rabbitmq only use the default suite.